# How to Pass Parameters to ORACLE stored procedure in SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using execute sql task to call a Oracle stored procedure,I want to pass a parameter     to a oracle stored procedure

Query Inside Execute sql task:-

```
BEGIN 
PKG_METRICS.GET_STUDY_METRIC(@myparameter, 'FIRST_SITE_SELECTED', 'LAST_SITE_SELECTED', 6, null,'SITE');
END;
```

Please let me know your comments...

Answer (score 0):

you should go to Expressions in SQL Task, 
then add expression to SqlStatementSource
and put this code inside dialog window:
`"BEGIN 
PKG_METRICS.GET_STUDY_METRIC("+`**@var_myparameter**`+", 'FIRST_SITE_SELECTED', 'LAST_SITE_SELECTED', 6, null,'SITE');
END;"`

Before that you should add string variable **@var_myparameter**.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the sql expression as a string as suggested above, but you can also pass parameters to Oracle if they are inputs to the ole db command in the pipeline.  Create an OLE DB Command block.  In the component properties enter the sql and place ? marks where parameters should be. Next go to input and output properties. Expand OLE DB command Input and add an external column for each parameter you need to pass. Order the MappedColumnId tabs from top to bottom starting with zero.  Map them to your inputs on the column mappings tab.

If your parameter is just a parameter in SSIS and not in the pipeline you could either add it to the pipeline with a simple derived column.  You can also just execute the proc from a script component using your favorite oracle access dll.

No perfect options, but there are ways to do this!

Answer (score -1):

In addition to **chrisPfeif518** :
for Oracle (in my case) , in OLE DB Command task , i used syntax:

```
{call ... }
```

for your case should be :

```
{call PKG_METRICS.GET_STUDY_METRIC(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)}
```